# Is it faster/better way to force authentication with NSURLConnection rather then using delegate method?

Tags: objective-c, ios, authentication, nsurlconnection

If I know that authentication is required for my server API, is it faster/better to directly force authentication using http header instead of waiting for the server to return 401 response and then respond to it inside NSURLConnection delegate method connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:?

Comment: Thilo, is your answer based on (me guessing here) that there is less communication between the client and server? And you might want add your -comment- as answer.

Comment: Yes, there will be one less server roundtrip. But without code samples how to do that in iOS, I don't feel it is more than a comment ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "easier way" to provide authentication credentials to a server is to use NSURLConnection delegate method

```
didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
```

where you can provide credentials similar to this

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {

    if ([challenge previousFailureCount] == 0) {

        NSURLCredential *newCredential;
        newCredential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:userName password:password persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone];
        [[challenge sender] useCredential:newCredential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    } else {
        [[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }
}
```

What will happen is that you first call server with your GET/POST request and if the server requires authentication, and credentials were not provided inside HTTTP header, it will (hopefully) respond with 401 response. The above method will trigger and provide supplied credentials.

But if you know that your server will always require authentication, it is not efficient to make this extra round of client/server communication and you will be better off to provide your credentials straight away inside the HTTP header.

The method of providing credentials inside HTTP header is simple apart from the fact that iOS doesn't come with a method to encode to BASE64.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *aRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:30];

// first create a plaintext string in the format username:password  
NSMutableString *loginString = (NSMutableString *)[@"" stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@:%@", userName, password];  

// encode loginString to Base64
// the Base64 class is not provided and you will have to write it!
NSString *encodedLoginData = [Base64 encode:[loginString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];  

// prepare the header value   
NSString *authHeader = [@"Basic " stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@", encodedLoginData];  

// add the authentication credential into the HTTP header
[request addValue:authHeader forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];  

// provide additional HTTP header properties (optional)     
[aRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[aRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[aRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

// and finally create your connection for above request
NSURLConnection *aConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:aRequest delegate:self];

// don't forget to release the request and nsurlconnection when appropriate...
```

Comment: Hi @peter-pajchl, thanks for the explanation. It worked for me. But still I am having a problem to load images from the server (that I think is due to the same authentication issue) with following line of code.
[myImageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[dic objectForKey:@"image"]]]]] ;

Can you please help me in

Comment: @SudhanshuSrivastava from the snippet of code it is hard to identify what could be the problem. I suggest you create a new question and provide more information as well as http responses you are getting. But things that you should look at...in your code I don't see where you are preparing the "request" and setting your credentials.